# Using the directions setup on a "My Map" using Google Maps

Tags: maps, google-search

I have followed the directions on Google Maps to create a map with a set of directions on as a layer. The advice I followed was [Here](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3502610?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

An example of what this looks like in the creation tool is:
[image]

and I can "preview" the map like so:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Owtp4cJZOX8dvnaZ9foH8LhlqwJ97Z7O&usp=sharing (should now be a public link)

But what I can't seem to work out is how to actually use those directions with the normal directions provided by google where I can route plan and get timings/distances etc.

I want to put that route into this view [image]

Comment: I have sent an access request to the link.

Comment: @DManokhin I've updated with a public link I believe

Comment: So what do you want to do?

Comment: Take those directions and press the "navigate by car" button and get timing/distances as well as a proper route. Like you get in the Google Maps app normally

Comment: I've added a picture of the normal view I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the side bar look for this:

[image]

Then select your mode of transport. Then click the three dots and click step-by-step directions. The view isn't exactly the same though but similar.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the only way, but useful none-the-less!